In the C preprocessor does #define incorporate previous #defines?
With these #defines without arguments
#define r 31
#define UMASK (0xffffffffUL<<r)
#define LMASK (0xffffffffUL ^ UMASK)

will UMASK be identical to (0xffffffffUL<<31) and LMASK be identical to (0xffffffffUL ^ (0xffffffffUL<<31)) in the actual code?  Which is
uint32_t x = (state_array[k] & UMASK) | (state_array[j] & LMASK);

I want the compiler to see it as
uint32_t x = (state_array[k] & 0x80000000UL) | (state_array[j] & 0x7fffffffUL);

I just cannot decode the standard enough to spell it out.

see https://godbolt.org/z/7EMff3hEb. This is using the pre-processor template.

I had already done that and it seems to compile correctly.  But I sorta don't trust it.  But for "educational" reasons (code example in Wikipedia), I wanted to use those #defines instead of the explicit masks.

"I just cannot decode the standard enough to spell it out." If you use gcc, you can use the -E command line option to create preprocessor output instead of compiling the code. Then you can check what your code looks like after replacing macros. That is not exactly the same as looking into the standard, but should be OK for majority of situations.

0xffffffffUL << 31 is pretty meaningless. Just write 1UL << 31.

What if r is not 31?  The purpose of the mask is to divide the bits of a word into two parts.  Here is the context.


will UMASK be identical to (0xffffffffUL<<31)

Yes.

and LMASK be identical to (0xffffffffUL ^ (0xffffffffUL<<31))

Yes.
As the macro replacement text for UMASK is scanned, the token r will be recognized as a macro and 31 will be copied, so the UMASK result follows.
As the macro replacement text for LMASK is scanned, the token UMASK will be recognized as a macro and expanded as before, so the LMASK result follows.
The C11 standard §6.10.3 Macro replacement ¶9 specifies the expansion of object-like macros:

A preprocessing directive of the form
# define identifier replacement-list new-line

defines an object-like macro that causes each subsequent instance of the macro name171) to be replaced by the replacement list of preprocessing tokens that constitute the remainder of the directive. The replacement list is then rescanned for more macro names as specified below.

Footnote 171 isn't germane to this discussion.
§6.10.3.4 Rescanning and further replacement details the scanning that occurs while processing the replacement text.

After all parameters in the replacement list have been substituted and # and ## processing has taken place, all placemarker preprocessing tokens are removed. The resulting preprocessing token sequence is then rescanned, along with all subsequent preprocessing tokens of the source file, for more macro names to replace.
If the name of the macro being replaced is found during this scan of the replacement list (not including the rest of the source file's preprocessing tokens), it is not replaced. Furthermore, if any nested replacements encounter the name of the macro being replaced, it is not replaced. These nonreplaced macro name preprocessing tokens are no longer available for further replacement even if they are later (re)examined in contexts in which that macro name preprocessing token would otherwise have been replaced.
The resulting completely macro-replaced preprocessing token sequence is not processed as a preprocessing directive even if it resembles one, but all pragma unary operator expressions within it are then processed as specified in 6.10.9 below.


thank you for confirming what the compiler already said, it's just that I worry.  I had written working C code for the Mersenne Twister PRNG and put it in Wikipedia.  I wanted it to reflect the text and symbols used in the body of the article, but making the bit masks were a little difficult to do that with concise code. - - - - - - 745k rep.  fuk.
